# いいじゃない vs よくない, whats the difference?

Tags: grammar

So in genki 1, it said that いい is changed to よ when being negative and it becomes よくない, and not いいじゃない. But I was watching a show and someone said いいじゃないですか. So now I'm kind of confused, can someone explain this to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

[いい](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%84%E3%81%84/#jn-9174) is a colloquial form of the adjective よい and is used only in dictionary/prenoun forms. Adjectives are negated not by じゃない, but by conjugation: よい→よくない, 青い→青くない.

[じゃない](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#) in いいじゃない means *isn't it*.

To clarify:

- Xはよい=Xはいい：X is good
- Xはよくない：X isn't good
- Xはいいじゃない：X is good, isn't it? (よいじゃない as a combination should be less common, because よい is less colloquial and じゃない is colloquial)

Comment: Basically, the negative of いい is よくない, never いいじゃない. Treat いいじゃない as its own separate fixed expression.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that sometimes 「よくない？」 with a rising intonation can also mean, "Isn't (it) good?". Also with the addition of ん you can sort of negate adjectives with じゃない; however it's quite rare and a bit different in it's meaning. For example: 「いいんじゃない」with a lowered intonation could take on a meaning like, "It's not that (it's) good." Most of the time with a rising intonation it would mean the same as 「いいじゃない」= "Isn't (it) good:?"

Comment: "is used only in dictionary/prenoun forms" Isn't いいですね correct?

Comment: @jarmanso7 いいですね is correct. いい is in prenoun form. Cf [体言、副詞、**形容詞**、一部の助動詞**の連体形**、助詞「の」に**付く**。](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99/#jn-151501)

Comment: @sundowner, okay, I guess "prenoun form" in Japanese does not really mean (only) "before nouns" strictly speaking, then. This is what I thought because you said "**only** in dictionary/prenoun forms".

Comment: With my limited knowledge of Japanese, I tried to come up with examples of いい where it is not modifying a noun, and that's what I found, いいです. Beyond that I couldn't come up with examples where よい is correct but いい isn't, maybe if you give some of them it would be helpful to understand your original point.

Comment: @jarmanso7 Sorry if it's inconsistent with learners' textbooks, but 連体形 (which I mean by prenoun form) refers to the form, not to the verb being in front of a noun.

Comment: @sundowner except that a more accurate translation of 連体形 in English would be "attributive" form rather than "prenoun" form, wouldn't it?  "prenoun" has a narrowly defined meaning in English regardless of the use you decided to give it liberally.

Comment: @jarmanso7 Yeah, possibly. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_conjugation#%E9%80%A3%E4%BD%93%E5%BD%A2) uses *attributive*, too. But I don't think *attributive* is particularly more appropriate. It is just a name of the form meaning 'the form that appears typically in front of a noun' (連体 literally means 'noun-connecting', which, due to the Japanese syntax, should be the same thing as 'prenoun').  To me, 'attributive' connotates the usage aspect as opposed to 'predicative', which has nothing to do with 連体形.